# Select only the forecast data from Table A that has a more recent date than the actuals from Table B

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Forecast and an Actuals table with Table structures as such:

```
YearNb, WeekNb, Country, Product, Volume
```

Now I am working on a third Table with the same structure that combines the two.
I already have a query that is simply importing all the actuals. Now I need to import all the Forecasts that are relevant. This leads to my problem. I only need the Forecasts that have a more recent Date than the actuals. The Forecasts table includes all historic forecasts, most of which are not relevant. I need to make this check on a country level, since we receive this data on a country level and different countries can have more or less recent actuals.

What I already did:

```
WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT Country, YearNb, WeekNb, (YearNb*100 + WeekNb) AS Date,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Country ORDER BY (YearNb*100 + WeekNb) DESC) AS rn
   FROM Actuals
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

This gives me a grouped list per country with the latest date of actual data.
But now I am kind of stuck how I could use this to select the data from the forecast table that has a more recent date.

```
Country YearNb  WeekNb  Date
A       2018      29    201829
B       2019       5    201905  
C       2018      34    201834
```

One important thing, I need this data on the product level, so to be in the same structure as the original two tables. 
So as final output I need all the Forecast per product for country A after the date 201829, all the data from Country B after the Date 201905 etc.

Comment: I'm confused on what you want.  Do you just want a list of forecasts?  Or do you want forecast/actual pairs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your own CTE you can get it

```
WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT Country, YearNb, WeekNb, (YearNb*100 + WeekNb) AS Date,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Country ORDER BY (YearNb*100 + WeekNb) DESC) AS rn
   FROM Actuals
)
SELECT f.*
FROM forecast f
JOIN cte ON f.Country = cte.Country AND cte.date < (f.YearNb*100 + f.WeekNb)
WHERE cte.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to JOIN by year `field` and add a condition to get earlier dates:

```
SELECT
*
FROM Actuals act
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT
    (
    SELECT 
    Country, YearNb, WeekNb, (YearNb*100 + WeekNb) AS Date,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Country ORDER BY (YearNb*100 + WeekNb) DESC) AS rn
    FROM Actuals
    WHERE  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Country ORDER BY (YearNb*100 + WeekNb) DESC) = 1
    )
    WHERE RN = 1
)q ON act.YearNb = q.YearNb and (act.YearNb*100 + act.WeekNb) < q.Date
```

Comment: Thanks for the input I will try this. I have  a question though, what is q in this case? Should I substitute this for my forecast table?

Comment: q is only alias here

Comment: @Tim `q` is alias for subquery. Its goal to name a subquery and to use in `ON` condition.

Comment: @Tim use aliases to avoid writing the whole table name. e.g. `SELECT p.Name FROM Person p`

Answer (score 2):

I would use a dependent query with `NOT EXISTS`

```
select YearNb, WeekNb, Country, Product, Volume
from Forecast f
where not exists (
  select 1
  from Actual a
  where a.country = f.country and
        a.YearNb * 100 + a.WeekNb >= f.YearNb * 100 + f.WeekNb
)
```

This select relevant data from your `Forecast` table. If you are considered about the performance, then `EXISTS` can perform better if you have an index on `country` attribute.

**EDIT**

If you want to omit `forecats` of countries that are not in actual then use a semi-join

```
select f.*
from Forecast f    
where not exists (
  select 1
  from Actual a
  where a.country = f.country and
        a.YearNb * 100 + a.WeekNb >= f.YearNb * 100 + f.WeekNb
) and 
exists(
  select 1
  from Actual a
  where a.country = f.country
)
```

Comment: So I was testing this and the issue I have is that this is also selecting data where I have no Salesdata for that date. So for example if I have forecasts in the table for 2016 Week 20 and for this week there is nothing in actuals, this query will also select it.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to select only forecasts for countries where you have at least one actual row with such country in `actuals`?

Comment: No what I mean is that I only want forecasts for the weeks that are actually more recent than the last week of actuals I have. So for example: I have actuals for the U.S. up to week 5 2019, but Im missing a week of actuals in 2018 week 50. I just want to select forecasts starting from week 6 2019. But with your query it will also select the forecasts for 2018 week 50, because this still fits the condition in your query. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @tim your comment is false, see https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2NxpJufeMfZRFABiyxpPps/2

Answer (score 0):

I would use `cross apply`:

```
select f.*, a.*
from (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by country order by yearnb desc, weeknb desc) as seqnum
      from actuals a
     ) a cross apply
     (select f.*
      from forecast f
      where f.country = a.country and
            (f.yearnb > a.yearnb or
             f.yearnb = a.yearnb and f.weeknb > a.weeknb
            )
     ) f
where a.seqnum = 1;
```

This makes it easy to choose columns from both tables.